# Reading values from external configuration file returns null values

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a configuration file `config.properties` that contains the following content:

```
myFirstName='John'  
myLastName='Doe'
```

I also have a very simple config class that simply outputs the values of the `config.properties` file:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.boot.Training.*"})
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class AppConfig {

    @Value("${myFirstName}")
    private static String myFirstName;

    @Value("${myLastName}")
    private static String myLastName;

    public static void showVariables() {
        System.out.println("firstName: " + myFirstName);
        System.out.println("lastName: " + myLastName);
    }

}
```

The problem is, when the values are output to the console, they appear null, even though they are obviously given a value in the `config.properties` file.:

```
2018-09-08 10:52:46.334  INFO 2787 --- [           main] c.b.Training.EnvironmentVariables.App    : Started App in 2.542 seconds (JVM running for 3.084)
firstName: null
lastName: null
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: may be that file is not on the classpath?

Comment: Can u remove quotes from your config file ? just provide like `key = value` . If not solve your problem , remove static keyword and try it once.

Comment: I think that the `static` keyword may be problematic here. Did you try to remove It? Also, usually the class which holds the properties is not annotated with `@Configuration`, but `@Component`

Comment: props file is not on the classpath or printout is made before initialization

Comment: Below from the @PropertySource ref page - might be worth specifying the full path of config.properties or dropping the * on ComponentScan -  Resource location wildcards (e.g. **/*.properties) are not permitted; each location must evaluate to exactly one .properties resource.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is about the `static` keyword. Because static fields initialization happens in  many processor-cycles before **Spring containers starts up**. So *remove* the `static` keyword from your class variable ;

```
@Value("${myFirstName}")
private String myFirstName;

@Value("${myLastName}")
private String myLastName;
```

**EDIT :** 
I added my code which is working correctly. And my main class which is starting spring context like this ;

```
public class AppMain {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        AbstractApplicationContext  context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        context.close();
    }

}
```

So In my `AppConfig.class` like this;

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.spring")
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
public class AppConfig implements InitializingBean {

    @Value("${firstKey}")
    private String myFirstName;

    @Value("${secondKey}")
    private String myLastName;

    public void showVariables() {
        System.out.println("firstName: " + myFirstName);
        System.out.println("lastName: " + myLastName);
    }

    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        showVariables();
    }
}
```

Dont care about implementing `InitializingBean` . It provide us what do u want when bean was created. Like a postConstruct as well.

Also my `application.configuration` is ;

```
firstKey = firsKeyValue
secondKey = secondKeyValue
```

Now when i am starting the app , i see this output ;

```
org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@37bba400: startup date [Sun Sep 09 11:37:35 EET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
firstName: firsKeyValue
lastName: secondKeyValue
```

It's working i think. Apply your requirements and try once.

Comment: I've removed the static keyword, and removed the quotes from the variable values in the properties file, but the results still return null.

Comment: Can u provide your usage of `AppConfig.class`.Where did you get this bean ?

Comment: Also i added new explanation in detail , can u check ?